# Failed to convert parameter value from a SqlParameter to a String

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

hi I have read all the previous similar issues but cant get it working

```
SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1];
param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Lot", SqlDbType.NChar, 112);
param[0].Value = "Bob123457";
DataSet ds1 = db.ExecuteDataSet("Getmagesbylot2", param );
```

my stored procedure is looking for a nchar (112) as a paramater
i've tried with and without quotes and with single quotes

Comment: Do you get an SqlException, or something else? I'm not an expert on this sort of stuff but would have assumed that since your field is nchar(112), your value of Bob123457  doesn't have enough characters, as opposed to nvarchar(112), which would allow less than 112 characters.

Comment: @Damith ExecuteDataSet is part of Enterprise Library. But yes, SP would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ExecuteDataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb748694%28v=pandp.60%29.aspx) call takes the actual parameter values, not `SqlParameter` objects.  Change it to simply do:

```
var ds1 = db.ExecuteDataSet("Getmagesbylot2", "Bob123457");
```

You might also want to check that you've spelled the SP correctly, maybe it should be `GetImagesByLot2`.

Comment: thanks tvanfosson that worked but if i want to pass more than 1 Param it gets messy and i spelled it wrong in both places so at least im consistant

Comment: @user3326577 but the method takes a params array of object. You need to pass those params as the method expects. Simply add the additional parameters to the method call as needed.

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
    SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1];
    param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Lot", SqlDbType.VarChar, 112);
    param[0].Value = "Bob123457";

    DataSet ds1 = db.ExecuteDataSet("Getmagesbylot2", param );

OR

    SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1];
    param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Lot", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 112);
    param[0].Value = "Bob123457";

    DataSet ds1 = db.ExecuteDataSet("Getmagesbylot2", param );
```

Comment: We don't yet know if OP's field (in the actual database) is nchar or varchar or nvarchar or something else

Comment: the field is nchar, i tried both suggestions but still get the same error  Failed to convert parameter value from a SqlParameter to a String.

Comment: -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
 @lot nchar (112)                                                                                                       

AS
BEGIN
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
 -- interfering with SELECT statements.
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
 SELECT TOP 1000 [Lot]
      
      
      ,[Date]
  FROM [Db].[dbo].[Material]
  where lot= @lot;
END