# How to Pass List<> to stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to pass a list to database (SQL Server 2008 R2) using user defined table types but get some errors my code is:

```
public int DAL_SaveIncramentSalary(tbl_Employee_Master obj, List < dtIncrementSalary > tbl) {
    try {
        SqlParameter[] objSqlParameter = new SqlParameter[4];
        objSqlParameter[0] = new SqlParameter("@Company_ID", obj.Company_ID);
        objSqlParameter[1] = new SqlParameter("@Employee_ID", obj.Employee_ID);
        objSqlParameter[2] = new SqlParameter("@Salary_Month", obj.Govt_DA);
        objSqlParameter[3] = new SqlParameter("@dt", SqlDbType.Structured);
        objSqlParameter[3].Value = tbl;
        objSqlParameter[3].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        DataSet fdd = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(_cnnString2, "usp_Insert_Increment_Salary_List", CommandType.StoredProcedure, bjSqlParameter);
        DataSet fddd = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(_cnnString2, "usp_Insert_Increment_Salary_List", objSqlParameter);
        DataSet ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(_cnnString2, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "usp_Insert_Increment_Salary_List", objSqlParameter);
        return SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(_cnnString2, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "usp_Insert_Increment_Salary_List", objSqlParameter);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I got error like this:

> Dataset dff error : Parameter count does not match Parameter Value count.    DataSet fddd error : ailed to convert parameter value from a List`1 to a IEnumerable`1.    DataSet ds error :Failed to convert parameter value from a List`1 to a IEnumerable`1.

SQL Server user defined type

```
CREATE type dtincrementsalary AS TABLE
(
    head_id INT NULL, 
    salamt NUMERIC(18,2) NULL, 
    per FLOAT NULL, 
    oldsalamt NUMERIC(18,2) NULL,  
    oldper FLOAT NULL 
) sql PROCALTER

PROCEDURE [DBO].[Usp_insert_increment_salary_list] ( @Company_ID  INT, 
                                                    @Employee_ID  INT, 
                                                    @Salary_Month INT, 
                                                    @dt DTINCREMENTSALARY readonly ) 
AS 
BEGIN 
  SELECT * 
  FROM   @dt 
END
```

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Comment: have a look into this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872141/failed-to-convert-parameter-value-from-a-sqlparameter-to-a-string

Comment: check my answer, it will work , if not then please let me know

Answer (score -1):

Issue in your code  `objSqlParameter[3].Value = tbl;`

`tbl is List<dtIncrementSalary>` but `SqlDbType.Structured` will take Table

suggest you to convert your `List<dtIncrementSalary>`  in `Datatable` with same schema as you created in Sql Server(`dtincrementsalary`)

Comment: thanks for reply, i am aware of data table pass to proc, but can i do with list with out convert into data table, can i pass list as it is ?? When i am pass the list in parameter it gives me  IEnumerable error, i also convert the list into IEnumerable and pass to parameter but it give me an error of No Mapping

Comment: as far as i Know you can't, if you find please let us know, Thanks